# Using Shader causes triangle to disappear

Tags: opengl, shaders, opentk

The following is my rendering code.

```
Private Sub GameRender()
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit + ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)
    GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue)

    GL.UseProgram(theProgram)

    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray)
    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray)

    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexPositionID)
    GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, 3)

    GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray)
    GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray)

    GlControl1.SwapBuffers()
End Sub
```

This is screenshot without `GL.UseProgram(theProgram)`
[image]

This is screenshot with `GL.UseProgram(theProgram)`
[image]

Here are my shader code that I picked from online tutorial.

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

These are my shader creation code.

```
    '' Initialize Shader
    Dim shaderList(1) As Integer
    shaderList(0) = CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader, strVertexShader)
    shaderList(1) = CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader, strFragShader)

    theProgram = CreateProgram(shaderList)

    GL.DeleteShader(shaderList(0))
    GL.DeleteShader(shaderList(1))
```

Here are my helper functions

```
Private Function CreateShader(ByVal shaderType As ShaderType, ByVal code As String)
    Dim shader As Integer = GL.CreateShader(shaderType)
    GL.ShaderSource(shader, code)
    GL.CompileShader(shader)

    Dim status As Integer
    GL.GetShader(shader, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, status)
    If status = False Then
        MsgBox(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(shader))
    End If

    Return shader
End Function

Private Function CreateProgram(ByVal shaderList() As Integer) As Integer
    Dim program As Integer = GL.CreateProgram()
    For i As Integer = 0 To shaderList.Length - 1
        GL.AttachShader(program, shaderList(i))
    Next
    GL.LinkProgram(program)

    Dim status As Integer
    GL.GetProgram(program, ProgramParameter.LinkStatus, status)
    If status = False Then
        MsgBox(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(program))
    End If

    For i As Integer = 0 To shaderList.Length - 1
        GL.DetachShader(program, shaderList(i))
    Next

    Return program
End Function
```

Comment: In your fragment shader you use 'outputColor'. Try changing it to 'gl_FragColor'.

Comment: I have replaced all 'outputColor' to 'gl_FragColor' with no luck. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Have you checked for OpenGL errors? Check for errors after your entire shader initialization, if you get an error, make your way back to the beginning by moving your error check before the function above the current one. Link for more information on the subject: http://www.opentk.com/node/1040

Comment: I have put the Msgbox(GL.GetError().ToString()) at the GameRender() function. It said "NoError". I guess there is something wrong with shader code, but I have no experience with shader language since I am just starting OpenGL. Do you know any other shade language sample that I can quickly plug and test.

Comment: UPDATE: Use `gl_Position = ftransform();` works, but OpenGL gave me a warning that it is depreciated.

Comment: Okay, change ftransform() to:
'gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex' with a semicolumn at the end.

Comment: @Basaa, basically, your code and ftransform() are depreciated since version 120 (that's what OpenGL said). If I change the version to 119, `ftransform` and `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex` work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9820/discussion-between-basaa-and-invisal)

Answer (score 0):

After

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
```

you want to use OpenGL > 2.0, this means that you need to store all your vertices in Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) which are bound to Vertex Array Objects (VAO).

For testing you should first comment the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix *` part and put your rectangle into the view volume (i think it was from x = -1 to x = 1 and the same for y)